# How to use a conditional statement with regex in PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell, if-statement, syntax, iteration

There are about ten lines of data.  For each line of data I want to indicate whether that line contains numerals.

How can I print out "yes, this line has numerals" or "no, this line has no numerals" for each and every line, exactly once?

output:

```
thufir@dur:~/flwor/csv$ 
thufir@dur:~/flwor/csv$ pwsh import.ps1 
no digits

Name
----                                                                           
people…                                                                        

thufir@dur:~/flwor/csv$
```

code:

```
$text = Get-Content -Raw ./people.csv
[array]::Reverse($text)

$tempAttributes = @()
$collectionOfPeople = @()

ForEach ($line in $text) { 
  if($line -notmatch '.*?[0-9].*?') {
    $tempAttributes += $line 
    Write-Host "matches digits"   
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "no digits"   
    $newPerson = [PSCustomObject]@{
      Name       = $line
      Attributes = $tempAttributes
    }
    $tempAttributes = @()
    $collectionOfPeople += $newPerson
  }
}

$collectionOfPeople
```

data:

```
people
joe
phone1
phone2
phone3
sue
cell4
home5
alice
atrib6
x7
y9
z10
```

The only reason I'm printing "digits" or "no digits" is as a marker to aid in building the object.

Comment: How about every time the text matches `^[^0-9]+$`, you print No Digits

Comment: Currently, your code will print No Digits every time there's something that does not match `[0-9]`. Do you see the problem? Every time it encounters a letter, it will print No Digits.

Comment: I want it to print "no digits" every time it encounters a string lacking digits...so at least three times (joe, sue, alice).  I'll update the question to try and clarify.  Not sure that I follow your thinking.  I don't want it to print "no digits" more than four times...certainly not for every character in a String of data...  **the print is just a marker to ensure the logic is working**

Comment: Currently, your code tells the regex to match ANYTHING that is not `[0-9]`, given by your code `$line -notmatch '[0-9]'`. Try to think about it from the computer's perspective, without common sense. 'J' is not a digit. 'o' is not a digit. 'e' is not a digit. So when it encounters 'Joe', it will print "No digits" **3** times.

Comment: Please try this code instead, `if($line -notmatch '.*?[0-9].*?')`

Comment: @RoboMop Thanks, I added that `regex`, I see what you mean.  I updated the question to try and clarify what output I'm looking for.

Comment: The output you've edited in the question - is that the output you're getting, or the one that you desire?

Comment: that's the output I'm getting.  I'd like to see output for each line: yes / no.  does this line have numerals?  Perhaps the `if` statement is running on the whole file itself??

Comment: I have zero knowledge about powershell, and I was trying to answer this with my experience with regex. It may very well be that - $line in $text may be giving you the entire file instead of one line

Comment: @RoboMop it was quite helpful!  No worries.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
switch -regex -file people.csv {
    '\d' { "yes" ; $_ }
    default { "no"; $_ }
}
```

`\d` is a regex character matching a digit. A `switch` statement with `-regex` allows for regex expressions to be used for matching text. The `default` condition is picked when no other condition is met. `$_` is the current line being processed.

`switch` is generally faster than `Get-Content` for line by line processing. Since you do want to perform certain actions per line, you likely don’t want to use the `-Raw` parameter because that will read in all file contents as one single string.

---

```
# For Reverse Output
$output = switch -regex -file people.csv {
    '\d' { "yes" ; $_ }
    default { "no"; $_ }
}
$output[($output.GetUpperBound(0))..0)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Perhaps a seperate question, but how could I reverse the input (read from bottom to top)?  I want to add each line to a custom object depending on the yes/no result.

Comment: You can just store the output in a variable and print it in reverse. See the edited code