# Using pattern matching to find String data with no digits in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, syntax, boolean

Looking to [match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60248417/262852) only `String`'s with [no](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/index.html#matching-digits) digits, using `\D` from `regex`.

Every string shows as `false`, but why?

Output:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/parseCSV$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/parseCSV$ gradle run

> Task :run                                                                                     
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:49 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO:           false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: z10               false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: y9                false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: x7                false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: atrib6            false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: alice             false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: home5             false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: cell4             false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: sue               false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: phone3            false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: phone2            false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: phone1            false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: joe               false
Feb. 16, 2020 5:24:50 A.M. parseCSV.FileHelper processLines
INFO: people            false

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/parseCSV$
```

relevant method [from](https://github.com/THUFIR/parseCSV) class:

```
public void processLines() {
    String regex = "\\D";
    boolean isDigit = false;
    for (String s : lines) {
        isDigit = Pattern.matches(regex, s);
        log.info(s + "\t\t" + Boolean.toString(isDigit)
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the regex pattern `^\D+$`, which matches one or *more* continuous non digit characters from start to end.  Since `Pattern#matches` implicitly covers the entire string, we can just use `\D+`:

```
public void processLines() {
    String regex = "\\D+";
    boolean isDigit = false;
    for (String s : lines) {
        isDigit = Pattern.matches(regex, s);
        log.info(s + "\t\t" + Boolean.toString(isDigit)
        );
    }
}
```